# Is it possible to create a base dialogfragment that binds strings using butterknife

Tags: android, butterknife

I'm trying to build a dialog that shows a list of items fetched from the network. Because I know that this isn't the only time that I will need this type of dialog I would like to build a base dialog (NetworkDialog) that handles the different errors that can happen when trying to fetch data from the network (ie. noServerResponse, failedToConnectToHost etc).

For this I would like to be able to use Butterknife to bind the string resources that are used for the different error messages, but I'm not sure if that will be possible.

Would something like this work?

```
public abstract class NetworkDialog extends BaseDialog implements NetworkDialogView {

    @BindString(R.string.global_network_error_internal_server_error)
    String mInternalServerErrorString;

    @BindString(R.string.global_network_error_no_server_response)
    String mNoServerResponseString;

    @BindString(R.string.global_network_error_no_network)
    String mNoNetworkString;

    @BindString(R.string.global_network_error_failed_to_connect_to_host)
    String mFailedToConnectToHost;
    private Unbinder mUnbinder;

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Timber.d("onCreateDialog()");
        Timber.d("Binding view using ButterKnife.");
        mUnbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this, getView());
        Timber.d("View bound");
        return super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        Timber.d("onDestroyView() called.");
        super.onDestroyView();
        mUnbinder.unbind();
    }

    @Override
    public void setNoNetworkError() {
        showError(mNoNetworkString);
    }

    @Override
    public void setFailedToConnectToHostError() {
        showError(mFailedToConnectToHost);
    }

    @Override
    public void setNoServerResonseError() {
        showError(mNoServerResponseString);
    }

    @Override
    public void setInternalServerError() {
        showError(mInternalServerErrorString);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried it out?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't work. Tried to move initialization of butterknife to onStart(), but this led to other problems because of not having access to the views earlier in the lifecycle.